lo_import realization in libpq of Postgresql
In the current implementation of lo_import, lo_write will be called each time for each 8KB of the file. 8KB is the buffer size set in LO_BUFSIZE. Why is it so small? It slows down the file upload by 30-40% because of lo_write sends  request and then waits response from a server.

That looks like a question for pgsql-hackers...

specifically for Tom Lane, who seems to have authored the corresponding commit

"Why" questions are usually impossible to answer. The mailing list archives contain no information, so we cannot tell. Odds are that nobody thought too hard about it.
I don't think that \lo_import has been optimized for performance. If you want to load large objects as quickly as possible, you can use the Large Object API directly and call lo_write() with bigger chunks.
That said, I suggest that you contact the pgsql-hackers mailing list and propose a patch to increase the buffer size. You'll need some performance measurements to back up your claim that a larger size is good for performance.
I want to recommend that you do not use large objects. They are obsolete, and the code doesn't get a lot of love.

I see that you wrote to the pgsql-general mailing list, but that's the wrong list. You should write to pgsql-hackers.
